# Animate a point alongside a line from known coordinates

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

In a JavaScript application that uses OpenLayers 4.5.0, where I have a linestring and a point in a map.  The point is located "on" the linestring.

Now, I want to move the point to an other location on the linestring, while animating alongside the line for a given period of time.

This is the information that I have, i.e. that I'm working with:

- I have the coordinate of the point
- I have the coordinate where to move the point to
- I have the geometry of the linestring
- I know that both coordinates (start and end) are on the line

I also have a good idea how to implement the animation.  What I do not know is how to obtain the location alonside the line while animating.

I'm aware of the method `ol.geom.LineString.prototype.getCoordinateAt`, which allows you to get a coordinate of a linestring given a fraction.  What I think I would need is the opposite: I have the coordinates.  **I need the fractions of the start and end**.  If I had those, I would be able to calculate the fraction between the two while animating.

Is there a way to accomplish this with OpenLayers?

### Update

Here's a picture that represents what I want to do.  More explanation below it.

[image: Preview of what I want to do]

1. I have a line string and point only.  The point is on the line (not at a vertex)
2. I get a new location where I want to move the point
3. I want to move the point alongside the line in an animation.  The arrow I drew is the path I want the point to move.  In other words, it's a sub-section of the line string from the original location of the point and its destination.

If I know the 2 fractions of the linestring in question (the ones at the start and end), then I could retreive the fraction while animating. If, for example, I know that the start is 0.2 and the end 0.8, then I'd know that if I'm 10% there in the animation, then I'd need to show my point to 0.26.

I hope this helps understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Have you seen the example -->https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html??????

Comment: Yes. In it, the point is moved from a vertex of the linestring to the other.  It is never moved on any segment, i.e. between two vertices.  I need to be able to do that.  Therefore, the example doesn't help.

Comment: I am not so sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish. If you just want to move on line segments , you may create a multiline geometry and then use the example provided. But as said, its not clear to me what is your goal. A fiddle would help though.

Comment: Added a snippet.

Comment: So as far as I understand. You have a linestring and two points (start/end). Splitting the line in these two points should give you the line you want to move your feature on. Is that correct?

Comment: if this is your case check this example --> https://viglino.github.io/ol3-ext/examples/map.interaction.split.html. It is not what exactly you want but it might help you.

Comment: Indeed, that looks like what I'm trying to accomplish.  I'll give it a look and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to accomplish what I needed to do using the **ol-ext** library, more specifically using the [splitAt](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext/blob/v2.0.0/src/geom/GeomUtils.js#L58) method.  Here's the recipe I used:

First, for each coordinated I had, I had to make sure that they "snap" to the line. I did so using the [getClosestPoint](http://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/apidoc/ol.geom.Geometry.html#getClosestPoint) method in OpenLayers, like so:

```
// Get "closest" start and end coordinates for segment computing
var closestStartCoordinate = lineString.getClosestPoint(startCoordinate);
var closestEndCoordinate = lineString.getClosestPoint(endCoordinate);
```

Then, if I use the **splitAt** method, I get multiple segments. The one I need is the one with start coordinate equal to `closestStartCoordinate` and end coordinate equal to `closestEndCoordinate`.

And that's it!  I have my segment.  While the animation is in progress, I'm able to use the [getCoordinateAt](http://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/apidoc/ol.geom.LineString.html#getCoordinateAt) method from the segment depending on the elapsed time of the animation to get the location to move my point to while it is in progress.

Thanks to @pavlos for pointing this out. Thanks to the authors of the ol-ext library!